# Converting a Date to Datetime gives error in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am storing a date in a `varchar(50)` column with values like thie:

```
1/01/2018
```

I want to convert these to a Datetime value eg: `2018-01-22 00:00:00.0000000`

My SQL is like;

```
select 
  [Site],
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), CAST([InvDay] AS DATETIME), 101) as Date,
from tableA;
```

But I am getting;

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

I tried like this also but same error;

```
CONVERT(datetime, [InvDay]) as  Date,
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Is this Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: In what representation is `'1/01/2018'` to be equal to "2018-01-22 00:00:00.0000000"?

Comment: @stickybit i want to convert Date to Datetime value. I provided example value for a datetime column

Comment: Well, technically you want to convert a `varchar(50)`, so a string, to a `datetime`. But my point is, given `'1/01/2018'`, I'd guess 2018 is the year portion. And the 1 and the other 01 is the day and the month. So up to "2018-01-" it's clear. But how can it be a 22 for the day portion when there's a 1 and a 01?

Comment: Date conversion issues are much more clear when the example has clearly defined month and day parts. `1/1/2018` could be either mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy, and I suspect an "out-of-range" means that you're trying to convert days to months, but with that example it's hard to say. If you change the example to have `22` in the day portion of the string it would help get the correct response.

Comment: Of course the other problem is that when you use a string to represent a date, you can just plain get bad data in the string field.

Comment: As someone who lives in a country that uses DMY rather than MDY, it used to drive me absolutely crazy that all the examples in the Microsoft documentation used to use 1st of Jan. It helped me not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the values that cannot be converted:

```
select invday
from tableA
where try_cast(invday as date) is null and invday is not null;
```

It is also unclear if your format is mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy.  You can specify a format using `convert()`:

```
-- mm/dd/yyyy
select invday
from tableA
where try_convert(date, invday, 101) is null and
      invday is not null;


-- dd/mm/yyyy
select invday
from tableA
where try_convert(date, invday, 103) is null and
      invday is not null;
```

Comment: Do you know, why I get above converting exception?I would like to get the converted datetime value also in varchar

Comment: @Ratha . . . Because you have a string that the database cannot convert.  That is why you should use `try_convert()` to see the bad value(s).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `set dateformat dmy`. Here is an example:

```
declare @d varchar(15) 
set @d='13/1/2018'
set dateformat dmy
select convert(datetime,@d)
```